# Duplicate the old data when the datagridview refreshed

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

i already can add the new data to the database and display that database through datagridview, and i command to refresh the datagridview whenever i click "Add" button (Adding new data to the database). But it is duplicate the old data with the new one.

Here is the screenshot that show it duplicate after adding new data and refresh datagridview:
[image]

In the above image, there is duplicate data of ID "16", whenever i enter the new value and insert it to the database, it add the new (current) value to the database, but the old value will be duplicated. Therefore, i have to quit the program and re-launch it again. But, is there any other ways to solve this (Old data not being duplicated after add a new data to the database and refresh the datagridview)?

Here is my code:

```
private void ViewDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM [Table]";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "Table");
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }


private void Add(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO [Table] ([ProductCode], [Quantity], [Description], [Price]) VALUES (@ProductCode, @Quantity, @Description, @Price)";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
                    cmd.Parameters["@ProductCode"].Value = this.numericTextBox1.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Quantity"].Value = this.numericUpDown1.Value;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = this.textBox3.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = this.textBox4.Text;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (choice.comboBox1.Text == "English")
                    {
                        System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                        sound.Play();

                        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            ViewDatabase(sender, e);

                            ClearTextBoxes(sender, e);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

Here

```
adapter.Fill(ds, "Table");
//here
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Edit:

Move

```
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

outside the using block it is nested in.

Comment: hai ahsan sallem, i already tried your code by adding `dataGridView.DataSource = null;` in below `adapter.Fill(ds, "Table")`, but it is still duplicate the old data.

Comment: try this 
adapter.Fill(ds, "Table");
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.Refresh();

AND move this line 
                  " dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];"
outside of the using block it is nested in.

Comment: No, it is still cannot @Ahsan Saleem